# How to use Blanket.js in test files loaded with Require.js?

Tags: javascript, requirejs, code-coverage, qunit, blanket.js

I am testing a JavaScript API using QUnit and BlanketJS and I separated it in multiple files for a better organization. I use RequireJS to load the files of the API.

The problem is, now I can't put the BlanketJS `data-cover` attribute on the JS files I want covered because I am no longer loading them with the common `<script>` tag. So this (below) is now impossible:

```
<script src="js/libs/api/api.js" data-cover></script>
```

How should I do to enable the coverage in my files?

Comment: No, I haven't. Sorry. :/